# CAShapeLayer cropping image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to crop an image using CAShapeLayer with this code

```
    CALayer* contentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CAShapeLayer* mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 10, 10);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 10, 80);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80, 80);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80, 10);
    mask.path = path;

    [contentLayer setContents:(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] CGImage]];
    [contentLayer setMask:mask];          

    [[self layer]addSublayer:contentLayer];
```

After executing this I can see just empty view;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set the `frame` of your `contentLayer`, so it defaults to `CGRectZero`, which makes its contents invisible. Set the frame to have the size of your image and you should see it.