# i want to crop image using any close path like UIBezierPath. it is possible in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, image-processing

i want to crop image in my iPhone app using any close path like UIBezierPath. i know it is possible using rectangle but i want crop in different shape. like i make one shape using touch and want to crop that image so how it is possible.
any suggestion or help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never did before but I suppose you need to use mage masking. Try read this apple Doc [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBDIJEE). Maybe you could create a transparent image with bezierPath programmatically or by user interaction and then use this image as mask for your original image.

Comment: Masking is the way to got. Have a look at this short example http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop your image with a shapelayer. To do it you have to create a path that will be used as borders for your new image. You should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637270/cashapelayer-croping-image).

```
CALayer* contentLayer = [CALayer layer];
[contentLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
CAShapeLayer* mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 10, 10);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 10, 80);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80, 80);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80, 10);
mask.path = path;

[contentLayer setContents:(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] CGImage]];
[contentLayer setMask:mask];          

[[self layer]addSublayer:contentLayer];
```

Something like this.

Comment: Vitaliy1 can you plz put the code here how to crop the image with shapelayer.....

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this using a mask. you can create a mask using `CGImageMaskCreate`.

if you need examples:

[Any idea why this image masking code does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133248/any-idea-why-this-image-masking-code-does-not-work)

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 0):

// In Code Use:

```
  -(UIImage *)croppedImage

{
   UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.bezierPath closePath];

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0,   0.0, 0.0);
_b_image = self.bg_imageview.image;

CGSize imageSize = _b_image.size;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self.bezierPath addClip];
[_b_image drawInRect:imageRect];
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return croppedImage;}
```