# Set Imageview With Dynamic frame

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, imageview

i need to set imageview Like this.
[image]

[image]
can anyone help?

thank in advance.

Comment: Please crop extractly your image.

Comment: I don't know what is problem here

Comment: this is image with dynamic frame.here top-Right and bottom-Right of image have different x and y coordinates.

Comment: there is nothing more complex . you don't need to give (width , height , OR aspect ratio) to ImageView . UIImageView will automatic take width/height based on image size. just give x and y for it. that's it.

Comment: do you mean the red area or all of image?

Comment: @GOPALVASANI i don't think `UIImageView` will automatic take width/height based on image size ;)

Comment: @Nimit , without trying how can u say that , just try it first.

Comment: @GOPALVASANI you are going to wrong way.i need to set different x and y position from top and bottom of imageview. it does't concert with image of autolayout

Comment: @GOPALVASANI i tried like you said and image didn't appear ;)

Comment: @Nimit i think the solution is you should create a new image with your image inside, you can put your image anywhere in your new image. After that set new image to UIImageView

Comment: @trungduc , if you can't see Image rendering in Xib then , may be your imagesize is not proper OR also check its name.

Comment: @GOPALVASANI Thank for your very helpful advance ;). Can you give me a small project to explain what you said is right?

Comment: @trungduc . here is the link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/th6awnvuj6u5sdu/ImageViewDemo.zip?dl=0

and you can see that , i have not gave any width/height constraint .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use UIBazierPath, on your image and set its frame, for that you will need to give it x and y values, so you should know the exact frame.

try this link:
[i want to crop image using any close path like UIBezierPath. it is possible in iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113330/i-want-to-crop-image-using-any-close-path-like-uibezierpath-it-is-possible-in-i)